# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui

I've been using jQuery UI autocomplete and it works perfectly in the development side. However, when I already deployed it (prod side), I cannot get it working. I used JS debugger in Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+J) ang got these errors:

```
jquery-1.4.4.js -Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Object Not Found)

jquery.ui.position.js -Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Object Not Found)

jquery.ui.widget.js -Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Object Not Found)

jquery.ui.core.js -Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Object Not Found)

jquery.ui.autocomplete.js -Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Object Not Found)

index.cfm:276Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

jquery.ui.all.css -Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Object Not Found)
```

This is a part of my code that references the scripts above:

```
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
           ...
```

I already double checked the paths and they are correct. I also tried changing $(function() to jQuery(function() but still doesn't work. I find it hard to debug because there are no errors in the dev side. Did I miss something here? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you say that the path is correct, it isn't. You have set relative URLs ass your `src`. Are you accessing that page from a subdirectory or anything? Try setting an absolute path (relative to your webroot).

Comment: @Blair McMillan Yeah, it may be my path that causes the problem. Thanks for pointing that out. So, should I include its absolute URL path like this: <script src="hTtPs://www.absolutepath.com/thisFolder/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script> ?

Comment: @Blair, I've tried doing the above reference. I used the absolute URL but still gives me the same errors (Failed to load resource). What shall I do?

Comment: @Blair, I tried accessing an index.html under jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom and the page can't be found. So maybe I should redeploy my files in the server. What do you think?

Comment: @Danielle, Yes, check that the files are deployed on the server correctly. Keep trying until you can access the file in a browser, once you can do that, then you can update the source in your HTML. With your example path before, you should only need `<script src="/thisFolder/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/..." type="text/javascript></script>` rather than having the `http://www.domain.com` at the start. Remember as well that in a lot of (common) servers, the paths are case sensitive. `thisFolder` is not the same as `thisfolder`.

Comment: @Danielle, Let me know how you go and what the cause is in the end.

Comment: @Blair, this is really weird. I saved the files again in the server and checked the path, still not working. I even copied the whole folder that contains these files from the server and tried to run it here in dev. And guess what, it runs properly. I know this problem should be simple. But debugging it is the difficult one because I have to deploy again and again in the server. Any other ideas why this happens?

Comment: @Danielle, if you put an image or something in that directory can you view it with your browser? If not, maybe it's a permission issue? Can you contact support for your host? Do you have support?

Comment: @Blair, hi! It's only now that I'm looking into this issue again because of other projects I've done in the past few days. Oh yeah, I'm using Coldfusion 6.1. Can it be a permission issue with Coldfusion? Or it has something to do with IIS? I'm such a newbie with these. Thanks again.

Comment: Did you try putting an image or something else in the same directory to view it?

Comment: Yes I did put an html file in that same directory, but the page can't be found. Maybe I should check on Coldfusion settings.

Comment: Yep, you'll need to check your settings then. I don't know anything about Coldfusion unfortunately, so I can't really help with that. You could try asking another question since we now know that it's related to not being able to access that particular directory. Also, do you have any other directories there that you *can* access? If you can access something in one of them, check its configuration, or perhaps just stick all of your JS into that folder as a bit of a work-around.

Comment: @Blair, thanks for patiently helping me. I'll check on the settings and hope I can get it working. If not, I'll try your work-around.

Comment: Hi everyone! I got this working, at last. What I did was I got all folders outside of jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom folder. That is, instead of /folder1/folder2/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js, I now have /folder1/folder2/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js.

I still don't get why the folder name jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom can't be found. If anyone knows why please tell me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly a path problem, might be the .js doesn't exists. Try, giving path from the root (absolute path)

Comment: Hi, I tried referencing the script using the absolute URL path. Example: <script src="hTTps://www.absolut path.com/this folder/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom/development-bundle/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script> It still doesn't work in the prod side. Still gives me error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Object Not Found).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error when trying to include a js in my  `<head>`

I moved the `<script></script>` closer to the `</body>` and it loaded ok...